# Not able to achieve the powershell azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell

I am trying to create azure function via Powershell script. Here trying to get public ingress IP but getting below error.

```
The Function app may be missing a module containing the 'az' command definition. If this command belongs to a module available on the PowerShell Gallery, add a reference to this module to requirements.psd1. Make sure this module is compatible with PowerShell 7. For more details, see https://aka.ms/functions-powershell-managed-dependency. If the module is installed but you are still getting this error, try to import the module explicitly by invoking Import-Module just before the command that produces the error: this will not fix the issue but will expose the root cause.
```

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}
$ingressName = $Request.Query.IngressName
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

$clientId = "cccccccccccccccc"
$clientSecret = "BBBBBBBBBBBBB"
$tenantId = "AAAAAAAAAAAA"

az cloud set --name azurecloud
az login --service-principal --username $clientId --password $clientSecret --tenant $tenantId

$env:KUBECONFIG = .\HttpTrigger1\cloud_config

kubectl config use-context $name

$ingressInfo = kubectl get services $ingressName -o json

$ingressObject = $ingressInfo | ConvertFrom-Json

$IP = $ingressObject.status.loadBalancer.ingress.ip

Write-Output $IP

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
#Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
 #   StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
 #   Body = $body
#})
```

I am new to azure functions. Does we have to manually install every module in powershell to login and execute commandlets.

Answer (score 1):

To run the PowerShell modules in Azure functions, you need to add the module in **requirements.psd1**.

```
@{ 
    'Az' = 'MAJOR_VERSION.*'
}
```

In Azure PowerShell function in the portal, it will install the  `Az`  module for you by default via the [Dependency management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#dependency-management)  feature.

For example, With the settings of your function, `Az` module will be installed automatically and login  `Az`  module with MSI of function app.
To use  `Az`  commands in the function, enable the MSI for your function app.

I have created a PowerShell Azure function locally:

**`host.json`**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "managedDependency": {
    "Enabled": true
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**`requirements.psd1`**

```
@{ 
    'Az' = '2.*'
}
```

**`profile.ps1`**

```
if ($env:MSI_SECRET) {
    Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
```

**run.ps1:**

```
using namespace System.Net

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

Import-Module Az.Resources
az login

$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($name) {
    $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}

Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

- Able to login to Azure and run the function locally.

[image]

To use these modules in portal=>Function App, you need to enable **managed Identity** in your function app.